# How to convert server time to local time using Joda?

Tags: java, jodatime, localtime

I'm developing application for mobile phone. So, after publish application will be ready for all users around the world. I need to adjust server time with local time of user. I thought maybe Joda (the library that i'm using) is able to do that. 
My question is how can I change server time to users local time.

Server returns "**2013-04-17T07:43:45Z**" as date/time.
After searching Internet I could parse it to "**17 Apr 2013, 07:43 AM**" successfully.
This is my method:

```
private String formatFanciedDate(String date) {
        date = date.substring(0 , date.length()-1); // Removing Z otherwise crash happens

        try {
            LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(date); // Like 2013-03-30T09:04:56.123
            return dt1.toString("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm a");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
```

However, this is not my local time (correct time should be around 15:00 PM). How can I change this time to my local time?

Comment: Just pass your local time to your method.

Comment: Hi Carsten, local time should be calculated based on server time.

Comment: Okay, I don't know what you want. Does your question have anything to do with the code you posted? Do you want to know how to calculate the difference between two dates? Do you want to know how to work mwith timezones in Joda? Do you want to know how to set the date and time on your server?

Comment: where you want to use your localtime on Browser? i dont understand your question

Comment: Thanks Carsten. My above code is based on Joda library. The problem is server sends its time. I need to change that time base on local time. For example in Sydney user should see 08:00 PM while another user in Singapore should see 06:00 PM, UAE should see 02:30PM and etc.

Comment: Hi nasir, I updated my question. Please check it again. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You strip the 'Z' from your input but that's the bit that specifies the time zone! Z means it is UTC. Without this information, Joda cannot make sense of the input.

What I think you are looking for is:

```
LocalDateTime local = new DateTime("2013-04-17T07:43:45Z").toLocalDateTime();
```